# Access to aurora Mysql db using MySqlPool quarkus reactive client and AWS IAM

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

Is it possible to access Aurora db using MySqlPool quarkus reactive client with AWS IAM ? Or is there any specific client like Amazon DynamoDbClient(for dynamo db access) in quarkus for Aurora Mysql db access ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like nobody has tried this. Can you try with the standard MySQL reactive extension in Quarkus and see what the result is. In theory Aurora is binary compatible with MySQL fo most basic things but reactive may or may not work.

Comment: I am using quarkus-reactive-mysql-client in the mvn dependency and using  
io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool to connect to db and execute queries in aurora db using master username and password. But in MySQLPool class I am not seeing any option to connect to Aurora db using IAM credentials. If it doesn't support that then I might need to use AWS SDK client to connect to the Mysql aurora db using IAM.